# CGridView change column width for raw type cell

Tags: html, yii

I am using CGridView with 'raw' cell type. The cell contains text field generated using CHtml::textField. Here I cannot change the width of the column using headerHtmlOptions or htmlOptions. Please help.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                    'id'=>'mbook-grid',
                    'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped dataTable',
                    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
                    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'calcquantity',
                    'enablePagination' => true,
                    'pagerCssClass'=>'dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap table-pagination',
                    'pager' => array('header'=>'','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pagination')),
                    'columns' => array(

                                        array(
                                        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                                        'id'=>'project_estimate_id',
                                        'htmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'display:none'),
                                        'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'display:none'),    
                                        'selectableRows'=>2,
                                        'value'=>'$data["project_estimate_id"]',
                                        'checked'=>'true',
                                        ),
                                        array('name'=>'description','value'=>'CHtml::textField("ProjectMBookGrid[description_".$data["project_estimate_id"]."]",$data["description"],array("class"=>"gridfield"))','type'=>'raw','header'=>'Description','headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 5%;')),
                                        array('name'=>'length','value'=>'CHtml::textField("ProjectMBookGrid[length_".$data["project_estimate_id"]."]",$data["length"],array("class"=>"gridfield","style"=>"text-align: right"))','type'=>'raw','header'=>'Length','headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:5%')),
                                        array('name'=>'breadth','value'=>'CHtml::textField("ProjectMBookGrid[breadth_".$data["project_estimate_id"]."]",$data["breadth"],array("class"=>"gridfield","style"=>"text-align: right"))','type'=>'raw','header'=>'Breadth','htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: right')),
                                        array('name'=>'quantity','value'=>'CHtml::textField("ProjectMBookGrid[quantity_".$data["project_estimate_id"]."]",$data["quantity"],array("class"=>"gridfield","style"=>"text-align: right"))','type'=>'raw','header'=>'Quantity','htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: right')),

                        ),
                            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view table-responsive hide-x-scroll'),
                ))
```

Below is the CSS

```
.table.dataTable {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.table-bordered.dataTable {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table {
    background-color: transparent;
    max-width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.hide-x-scroll {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.grid-view {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code contains errors. Like `array(name=>'length'` must be `array('name' => 'length')`. Also please format your code to be readable. Also show full css applied for table. Maybe `table {table-layout: fixed;}` may help

Comment: @Justinas      Updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
"style"=>"width:100%"
```

in CHtml::textField htmlOptions and was able to change the width of column